# View detailed warnings in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

How do you view detailed warnings in MySQL workbench? When I execute a command, all I see is a brief summary of /how many/ warnings there were. I'd like to see a detailed report of what the actual warnings contained.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

mysql has great documentation about showing warnings

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html

Comment: SHOW WARNINGS is not returning any results after trying to import a script from a database dump that keeps failing.